# iPhone development custom shaped UIImageview

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I would like to know how to create a custom shaped uiimageview so that around the shape I'll be able to see the app's background.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Image view will be rectangular in shape. It does not need to be in a custom shape. It is transparent. Populate your image view with a png image of your shape with transparent background and you'll 'be able to see the app's background'.